# The convergence of unordered sum on product sets

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

I am working on the following problem from Chapter 2 of Kelley, and I can not work out part h.(iii) of this question.
[image: 2.G]

I think this problem can be reduced into the following statement:

**Proposition** *Given real values $A_1,A_2,\cdots$ and $B_1,B_2,\cdots$, then there are some $\left\{a_{ij}\right\}_{i,j\in\mathbb{N}}$, such that for arbitrary $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum^\infty_{i=1}a_{n_0,i}$ converges absolutely and $\sum^\infty_{i=1}a_{n_0,i}=A_{n_0}$, and for arbitrary $m_0\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sum^\infty_{j=1}a_{j,m_0}$ converges absolutely and $\sum^\infty_{j=1}a_{j,m_0}=B_{m_0}$.*

Here is a picture which visualise the proposition, in which every row and column converges absolutely.
$$\begin{matrix}
  \quad  &A_1  & A_2 &A_3  & \cdots\\
  B_1& a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} &\cdots  \\
 B_2 & a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} &\cdots \\
 B_3 & a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} &\cdots \\
 \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots  &
\end{matrix}$$

How can I prove it? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with $a_{11} = A_1$. We have our sum in the first column, so can say $a_{i1} = 0$ for $i > 1$.

Now, we need to sum the rest of the first row to $B_1 - a_{11}$. Let's not overcomplicate it and just say $a_{12} = B_1 - a_{11}$ and $a_{1i} = 0$ if $i > 2$.

Now, we are done with first row and column. The rest go similar: $a_{22} = A_2 - a_{12}$, $a_{23} = B_2 - a_{22}$ and so on, $a_{ii} = A_i - a_{i-1,i}$ and $a_{i,i+1} = B_i - a_{ii}$, with the rest of $a$'s be zero.

All the sums mentioned have just two non-zero terms, so for sure converge absolutely.

Comment: I really apperciate it! Thank you very much!